# Python: module for plotting Gantt charts

Tags: python, gantt-chart

Is there a good Python module for plotting [Gantt Charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart)? I've tried [CairoPlot](http://linil.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/cairoplot-11/), but it produces buggy results for complex data sets and lacks many configuration options.

Code samples and images are highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ChartDirector is pretty good at generating advanced charts of all kinds. It has decent python bindings, but it's, unfortunately, not native python or open source in general.

There are actually some [Gantt chart examples/screenshots](http://www.advsofteng.com/gallery_gantt.html). The code also includes python demo's for building gantt charts.

If you're working on a web application, you can also consider [Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). It appears to be flexible/advanced enough for simple, [Gantt-like charts](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhs&chs=600x200&chd=t:0,3,4,10,11|3,1,0,0,0|0,0,6,0,0|0,0,0,0,0|0,0,0,1,3|0,0,0,0,0&chds=0,14&chco=ffffff00,000000,00ff00,ff0000,0000ff,ff6600&chtt=Sample+Project&chdl=|Complete|On+Time|Late|Upcoming|Other&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|12%2F04|12%2F05|12%2F06|12%2F07|12%2F08|12%2F09|12%2F10|12%2F11|12%2F12|12%2F13|12%2F14|12%2F15|12%2F16|12%2F17|12%2F18|1:|Step+5|Step+4|Step+3|Step+2|Step+1&chg=7.1,0&chm=r,99ccff44,0,0,0.29). You can read more on this [here, for example](http://www.designinginteractive.com/code/how-to-build-a-gantt-chart-with-the-google-charts-api/). Or just google for "google chart gantt"

Answer (score 7):

Plotly has very good gantt charts. check out their documentation and examples in the following link

https://plot.ly/python/gantt/

Answer (score 6):

You should also check [faces](http://faces.homeip.net/), it's a powerful and free project management tool that you *program* with python. It's also built in python. It can output many different charts, including gantt chart.

Comment: That project seems to be dead, is there active fork somewhere?

Comment: It is now incorporated in OpenERP (http://www.openerp.com/). It's use in *Resource* and *Long Term Project management* modules I think.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout [Python Gantt](https://xael.org/pages/python-gantt-en.html)

Python-Gantt make possible to easily draw gantt charts from Python. Output format is SVG.

[image]

you can install through pip

```
pip install python-gantt
```

Comment: This is great work but it sadly lacks customization and the presets are pretty ugly. Also, it has bugs (I tried plotting on a weekly basis and the `duration` argument created wrong plotting ranges).

Comment: Note license there is GPL

Answer (score 0):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) can produce something similar -- see [this sample](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_90.html#Bars-fall-sample). The same can be done for horizontal bars too.

Answer (score -2):

python-gantt doesn't work
It raised this error after trying module import
AttributeError: module 'gantt' has no attribute 'define_font_attributes'

Comment: Please provide quality answers until you can write comments. This commentary like answer is not enough.

Comment: This is misplaced answer, but true.